# From a given Redis cluster, how can I run a Redis CLI or API call to get a list of EVERY key on that whole cluster, not just one machine?

Tags: python, redis, redis-cli, redis-cluster

This is only for initial Redis setup. Obviously, on production systems, a dump of the entire multi-machine database would be difficult to sort through.

I'd accept an answer in any language, although I prefer Python.

A simple Redis CLI command for this would work, too.

Answer (score 3):

Redis implements clustering using sentinel.

Read more on sentinel - http://redis.io/topics/sentinel

Connect to the redis instance using `redis-cli -h hostname -p port` from terminal.

Run `KEYS *` command to get all the keys on that Redis instance.

`KEYS` command takes regex as the argument (* for all).

If you are trying to access it from code .. there are various modules available. I have tried using node-redis, for Node Js.

However on production I don't recommend you to use `KEYS` command as it takes a considerable time for millions on keys, rather use `SCAN` command to scan a number of keys its syntax is `SCAN CURSOR MATCH match COUNT count`.. eg `SCAN 0 MATCH * COUNT 10000`..initially the cursor is taken as 0 as the iteration for further keys is stopped when the cursor returned is 0.

Comment: // , Ah, so I must do this on each instance, one by one, rather than a whole cluster all at once, as I had hoped for.

Comment: Yes to get a dump of all keys you need to connect to each instance  and execute keys or scan command.... However if u just want to know the number of keys in redis instance for redis 2.6 and above, lua is supported, you can get number of wildcard keys like this

`eval "return #redis.call('keys', 'prefix-*')" 0`

Answer (score 1):

```
from redis import StrictRedis
red = StrictRedis(host='127.0.0.1')
all_keys=red.keys("*")
```